# copy data from one table to another where column count is different

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
table_1
-------
id,name,address

table_2
-------
id,name,address,phone_no
```

I want to copy all data from table_1 to table_2. When I execute the following query it throws an error.

```
mysql> insert into table_2 select * from table_1;
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Comment: If you insert data select to another `table` you need to specify same column for both `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the columns:

```
insert into table_2 (id, name, address) select (id, name, address) from table_1
```

Of course, the `id` needs to be insertable (not a generated value) and `phone_no` needs to allow `null` values (otherwise you'd have to specify a default value).

Comment: @r0xette: Can you copy/paste the actual query and output you're getting and edit it into the question, just as you originally did?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood it. Let me change it and try again.

Comment: This answer looks fine to me based on `NULL` comment

Comment: It worked. I had one column which had no default value set and couldn't accept the null value so I changed it.

Comment: Keep in mind that MySQL differentiates between '' and NULL (empty string vs no string).  If you really want to open up a can of worms that will drive you crazy, use ''.  You can also either set a default or add a default value to the insert.  Keep in mind that using a default table value will add that default if another query attempts to violate the mandatory attribute of the column and will not be stopped.  So, when you're copying data, it's safer to add a value to the insert, and NOT create a default value for a phone field.